# Calculating a daily average (or: how many Mondays are in a date range?)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

My MySQL table has the following columns: datetime, price_paid.
I'm trying to calculate the average sales per day of the week, between 2 dates. 
This means I need select the sum of sales, between the dates startDate and endDate, grouped by weekday and divide that by the number of times every weekday occurs in that range.

I got the first part:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%a') AS field1, 
round(SUM(price_paid)/ THEVALUEIMLOOKINGFOR ) AS field2 
FROM Bills 
WHERE date(datetime) BETWEEN '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-09' 
GROUP BY weekday(datetime)
```

What I don't have is that missing value: the number I should divide by - number of times each day appeared in that range. I tried several solutions, to no avail.

Can someone please help me complete my SQL statement?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So, do you ultimately want to see something like Daily Averages: Mon, Tue, Wed, etc... during the date range?  If so, some range might have only 2 Wed vs 3 Mon and Tue (or other similar)...

Comment: Correct - I need a daily average. I hope the solution below takes that into consideration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

maybe I'm being too simplistic, but given that you're already grouping by weekday, wouldn't just count(*) compute the number of the given weekday in that range, for every weekday?

so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%a') AS field1, 
round(SUM(price_paid)/ COUNT(DISTINCT(date(datetime))) ) AS field2 
FROM Bills 
WHERE date(datetime) BETWEEN '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-09' 
GROUP BY weekday(datetime)
```

edited so not overcounting multiple times the same day (thanks DRapp)

Comment: I think you are VERY close... however, if they had multiple bills on the same date, you would over count the divisor.  COUNT( DISTINCT  ) on a formatted yyyy-mm-dd would help to ensure that...

Comment: so then `COUNT(DISTINCT(date(datetime))`

Comment: Thanks for answering. One question though: will this cover a case where the date range is 8 days (i.e. there are 2 Mondays, say) and therefore you need to divide buy 2 Mondays? Will the Distinct still be necessary?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy, it should be correct.  if 8 days, the totals spanning BOTH Monday's would be divided by 2... However, Tue-Sun will all just be divided by the 1 instance each... Run with some sample data and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but "seems to work". isn't quite good enough. 
In fact, It will under count the number of Mondays if there was a day with ZERO transactions.

There is a formula for counting days of week in a date range. You need to start with a known day of the week.  "1970-01-05" was a MONDAY.

Here is a function you can use:

```
create function CountDaysOfWeek(
    DateFrom DATETIME,
    DateTo DATETIME,
    DayOfWeek int
)
RETURNS int
return FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DateTo,'1970-01-03' + INTERVAL DayOfWeek DAY)/7) - 
   FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DateFrom,'1970-01-03' + INTERVAL (DayOfWeek+1) DAY)/7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stored function called MakeDateList:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `junk`.`MakeDateList` $$

CREATE FUNCTION `junk`.`MakeDateList`
(
  BeginDate DATE,
  EndDate DATE,
  InclusionList VARCHAR(20)
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(4096)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE RunningDate DATE;
  DECLARE rv VARCHAR(4096);
  DECLARE comma CHAR(1);
  DECLARE IncList,DOWValue VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE OK_To_Add INT;

  SET IncList = CONCAT(',',InclusionList,',');
  SET comma = '';
  SET rv = '';
  SET RunningDate = BeginDate;

  WHILE RunningDate <= EndDate DO
    SET OK_To_Add = 0;
    SET DOWValue = CONCAT(',',DAYOFWEEK(RunningDate),',');
    IF LOCATE(DOWValue,IncList) > 0 THEN
      SET OK_To_Add = 1;
    END IF;
    IF OK_To_Add = 1 THEN
       SET rv = CONCAT(rv,comma,RunningDate);
    END IF;
    SET comma = ',';
    SET RunningDate = RunningDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
  END WHILE;
RETURN rv;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It has three parameters: BeginDate, EndDate, and InclusionList

InclusionList is a comma speararted list of numbers (valid numbers 1-7)

```
1 = Sunday
2 = Monday
3 = Tuesday
4 = Wednesday
5 = Thursday
6 = Friday
7 = Saturday
```

So to get Mondays, make the InclusionList 2

Example : Calling MakeDateList('2011-10-01','2011-10-01','2') should give you Mondays for the whole month of October 2011

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a sum of averages then you need to use a subquery to compute the averages for each day, then you compute the sum of the averages.

I have modified the query to include an external query which returns the total of the averages. However now the field1 will not make sense anymore since it can be any of the dates depending on which ordering option you use

```
SELECT field1, SUM (field2) FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%a') AS field1, 
  AVG(price_paid) AS field2 
  FROM Bills 
  WHERE date(datetime) BETWEEN '2012-01-02' AND '2012-01-09' 
  GROUP BY weekday(datetime)
)
```

Comment: Tried this. This returns the average per _a_ day, not the total of averages. Thanks