# How to Count Friday Between specific dates

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(DAYNAME='FRIDAY') WHERE date between 2020-05-05 AND 2020-06-09
```

Without Depend on any tables

I try to use  build in function but I don't now how I get it

Comment: Something like: `select floor(datediff('2020-06-29','2020-05-05')/7);` but you might need to 1.  What did you try ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count specific days of week between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460158/count-specific-days-of-week-between-two-dates)

Comment: yes but I need to Count  Fridays

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a little creative, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/jTMjWjLy)

```sql
set @start = '2020-05-05'; -- Tuesday
set @end = '2020-06-29';  -- Monday

with recursive dates as (
  select 
     cast(@start as DATE) as FromDate,
     1 as NumberOfDays
  union all
  select 
     FromDate,
     NumberOfDays+1
  from dates where NumberofDays < DATEDIFF(@end,@start)+1
  )
select 
   FromDate,
   DAYNAME(FromDate) as NameFrom,
   DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL NumberOfDays DAY) as ToDate,
   DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL NumberOfDays DAY)) as NameTo,
   DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL NumberOfDays DAY)) as DOW,
   round(datediff(DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL NumberOfDays DAY), FromDate)/7,0)
     + CASE WHEN DayOfWEEK(DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL NumberOfDays DAY))=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Fridays
from dates
```

NOTE:

1. The table is only used for testing.
2. Some more testing might be needed to check if changing StartDate does work OK with all edge cases.

If testing all cases is OK you can do:

```sql
set @start = '2020-05-05'; -- Tuesday
set @end = '2020-06-29';  -- Monday

SELECT 
   @start as FromDate,
   @end as ToDate,
   round(datediff(@end, @start)/7,0)
     + CASE WHEN DayOfWEEK(@end)=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Fridays;
```

Comment: Its doesn't work because there is no Accuracy

Comment: "Accuracy" ? What do you mean ?

Comment: I tried some dates and some time results isn't right

Comment: (datediff('2022-11-25','2022-11-4') here we have 4 fridays result is only 3